# MVC Razor RadioButtonList onchange handler

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, radiobuttonlist

I have use HTML helpers (RadioButtonLists, DropDownListFor and EnumDropDownListFor) for my radio buttons and dropdowns. Example:

```
@Html.RadioButtonList(m => m.ItemType, new SelectList(Model.ItemTypes, "Name", "Name")
```

and

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.ApartmentFloor, new SelectList(Model.ApartmentFloors, "Id", "Floor"), new { @id = "floorsSelect", @class = "exists" })
```

For the DropDownListFor, there seems to be ways to set HTML properties for the list, eg. id, class, style etc.
But for the RadioButtonList, which is acctually a custom class ([my version](http://pastebin.com/Qwxj5ZXU) and [original](http://jonlanceley.blogspot.dk/2011/06/mvc3-radiobuttonlist-helper.html)), I cant seem to find a way to add those types of properties.

The one I had in mind is "onchange". How do you add onchange functions to these types of helpers?

Comment: You should add the handler in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

See the rendered html for your "RadioButtonList" & get the id of the control, then you can easily associate "onchange" event using following jQuery Code.

```
$("#RadioButtonListID input").change(function(){
//Write Your Code Here
});
```